# How to prevent flutter app from crashing after Dio error?

Tags: flutter, dio

I am using the `flutter-dio` package to make HTTP requests and have made a wrapper on it from my convenience like so

```dart
  Future<dynamic> post(String uri, dynamic body, {String authKeyCust}) async {
    authKey = await SecureStorage.getAuthKey();
    try {
      Response response = await dio.post(
        uri,
        data: body,
        options: Options(headers: {"authkey": authKeyCust ?? "$authKey"}),
      );
      return response.data;
    } on DioError catch (error) {
      print('error: $error');
    } on SocketException catch(error) {
      print('No net');
    }
  }
```

All I want is the app to not *crash/pause on exception* when any error occurs.

Comment: I don't understand, what is your problem ?

Comment: @woprandi Whenever there is an exception raised, the debugger stops the app, even if I am catching the error

Comment: Post your code here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the same problem.

First, try to run it from command prompt with `flutter run` see if there is occurring any problem or not.

If the command prompt is showing no problem & your app is running smoothly then you have to check the IDE. If you are using VSCode then switch to Debug is side bar, see which options are ticked in Breakpoint section.
If `All Exceptions` is ticked then the debugger will pause on every exception. Uncheck both `All Exceptions` & `Uncaught Exceptions` then try refresh restart.

Hope this will solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the catch just work fine, i mean it is not an uncaught exception in this case?